# For loop repeats and generates more values than what is specified

Tags: python

I am trying to paste 3 rectangular images on a canvas. The goal is that the images are within the canvas and they do not overlap. For this, I decided to generate 3 two-tuple values that will serve as the locations of the xy coordinates of the image's top-left corner. Something like this:

```
locations_used = [(950, 916), (1097, 119), (1290, 526)]
```

What it instead does is that it repeats the first value 3x and then adds the 2 new values, giving me a total of 5 positions when I've specified 3. Like this:

```
[(950, 916), (950, 916), (950, 916), (1097, 119), (1290, 526)]
```

This is an MRE of my code:

```
    n = 3
    canvas_width = 500
    canvas_height = 300
    logo_width = 50
    logo_height = 30
    locations_used = []
    
    for i in range(0, n):
        
        logo_location_x, logo_location_y = logo_position(canvas_width, canvas_height, logo_width, logo_height)
        locations_used.append((logo_location_x, logo_location_y))

        for img in locations_used:
            if logo_location_x in range(img[0], logo_width) or logo_location_y in range(img[1], logo_height):
                pass
        else:
            while len(locations_used) < n:
                locations_used.append((logo_location_x, logo_location_y))

     print(len(locations_used))
     print(locations_used)
     print('\n')
```

The output:

```
5
[(950, 916), (950, 916), (950, 916), (1097, 119), (1290, 526)]
```

Comment: You have a while loop that will add a location to the list until the length of that list is 3 and so I'd put money on that being the culprit here.

Comment: I'd also put my money there but idk how to fix it.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you have that while loop. Since your first loop runs from 1 to n, a good way to ensure that you only add n locations to the list is to have only one append call that is run on each iteration of that for loop and nowhere else. 

Are you trying to randomly sample locations until you find one that results in no overlap?

Comment: @Alex I am trying to make sure that the list gets inflated while it is below n. When I remove the while loop, the list gets 6 tuple entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first iteration, `logo_location_x`(950) and `logo_location_y`(916) are compared to `range(950, 50)` and `range(916, 30)`. Since `start` parameter is smaller than `stop`, range is empty and program procedes to `else` clause. While length of `locations_used` is under 3, same values will be added, thus making the array `[(950, 916), (950, 916), (950, 916]`.

In the next two iterations, each new `x, y` pair get added to `locations_used`. While `range(img[0], logo_width)` and `range(img[1], logo_height)` are still empty, length of `locations_used` is greater than `n` so no additional element will be added.

This is edited code to create `n` not overlaping positions.

```py
# Instead of iterating only 3 times, try until list is full.
while len(locations_used) < n:
        
    logo_location_x, logo_location_y = logo_position(canvas_width, canvas_height, logo_width, logo_height)
    
    # Don't add position until it is checked that it doesn't overlap.
    # locations_used.append((logo_location_x, logo_location_y))

    # Check if new rectangle candidate overlaps with previous ones.
    overlap = False
    for img in locations_used:
        # Fix range usage. I hope this is what you want.
        if logo_location_x in range(img[0] - logo_width, img[0] + logo_width) and logo_location_y in range(img[1] - logo_height, img[1] + logo_height):
            overlap = True
            break
    
    # Add position to list after you ensure that new position
    if not overlap:
        locations_used.append((logo_location_x, logo_location_y))
```

Comment: How do you think I should go about fixing this?

Comment: @oo92 What exactly are you trying to achieve? I see that you made position of three rectangles, but I don't know what you want to do with them.

Comment: The positions of these rectangles need to stay within the canvas AND they cannot overlap. I will apply the positions in another function and that one is already written. For this, I just want to append 3 unique positions that meet the criteria mentioned.

Comment: @oo92 I edited your function, check it out.

Comment: `# Don't add position until it is checked that it doesn't overlap.`
You need to add 1 position first so that your list is not empty. The 2nd entry will avoid overlapping the 1st and the 3rd entry will avoid overlapping both..

Comment: @oo92 Why? If locations_used is empty there is no previous rectangle to compare so it will skip to append part.

Comment: I just ran your code and it still gives me 5 entries..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227937/discussion-between-marksouls-and-oo92).